# How to organize content .vimrc in multiple files

Tags: vim, plugins

Is there any methodology to organize the content of .vimrc in multiple files?

Currently my .vimrc has everything: Plugs statement, remaps, sets,functions,mapleader, custom plugins configuration, autogroup, etc.

I would like to organize in multiple files, perhaps by language.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split the contents of .vimrc into different files. Then source those files from within vimrc. Example:

```
" File:      vimrc                                                           
" Author:    Jonh Doe                                                

" Options, commands, and auto commands                              
runtime settings.vim

" Maps                              
runtime maps.vim                                                                      
                          
" Functions
runtime functions.vim

" Plugin settings                                             
runtime plug-settings.vim
```

Filetype-specific settings should be stored under `~/.vim/ftplugin`, or [less commonly](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/when-to-use-the-after-directory), under `~/.vim/after/ftplugin`. For example, html settings should be in `~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim`.

I suggest to take a look at vimrcs of experienced vim users.  [This repository](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc) should be a good starting point.

Comment: This is neither scalable nor portable. `:help :runtime` is prefered to `:help :source`.

Comment: I see, so `source $HOME/.vim/settings.vim` is not portable because some OSes (like Windows) have backslash `\ ` in paths. A better choice is `runtime settings.vim`.

Comment: @romainlcan could you elaborate?

Comment: @builder-7000 both `/ ` and `\ ` are valid path separators in Windows. `\ ` is more common

Answer (score 1):

After your `~/.vimrc`, Vim starts sourcing the `plugin/` scripts. For your own mappings and custom commands, you can just place them anywhere in there, e.g. `~/.vim/plugin/MySuperCommand.vim` and `~/.vim/plugin/MyLifeSaverMappings.vim`.

For customization of other plugins, or Vim options that influence the behavior of plugins, it is crucial that these execute *before* the plugin(s). By using the `~/.vimrc` (the general recommendation), this is ensured automatically. You can explicitly `:runtime` the scripts from your `~/.vimrc`, as per @Sergio's answer, or define them as plugin scripts, too, but ensure that they run first:

- If you install plugins the traditional way (in `~/.vim/plugin/`), you can use the script naming (e.g. `00MyStuff.vim`) to influence loading order.
- If you use pack plugins, or a package manager, just ensure that your own plugin directory comes first in the `'runtimepath'`.

The `:scriptnames` command is a valuable troubleshooting tool to verify that the script loading order is correct.